# Como hacer que aparezca una imagen cuando apreto un boton en python, utilizando tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo en lo que es python y estoy experimentando un poco. Ultimamente estoy intentando de realizar un programa que al apretar un botón aparece una imagen en la pantalla.

El programa no me tira ningún error, pero no me da el resultado esperado cuando lo corro. Cuando apreto alguno de los botones me aparece un recuadro en blanco donde debería aparecer la imagen.

```
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()

miframe=Frame(raiz)
miframe.pack()
miframe.config(bg="black",width=800, height=600)


valor = StringVar()

def codigoBoton(valor):

        if valor=="parabola":
            imagen=PhotoImage(file="parabola.png")
            imgcuad=Label(miframe,image=imagen)
            imgcuad.grid(row=1, column=2)


parab=Button(miframe, text="parabola", command=lambda:codigoBoton("parabola"))
parab.grid(row=1, column=1)


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

La imagen que leiste se encuentra en una variable local la cual es [eliminada por el recolector de basura](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm). Para mantener la referencia tienes que agregar (según tu código) `imgcuad.image=imagen`

```
def codigoBoton(valor):

    if valor=="parabola":
        imagen=PhotoImage(file="parabola.png")
        imgcuad=Label(miframe,image=imagen)
        imgcuad.image=imagen
        imgcuad.grid(row=1, column=2)
```